# TIBCO SPOTFIRE Time on y-axis (avg duration)

Tags: tibco, spotfire

New user to Spotfire, I'm struggling to find a way to display the average time on the y-axis with a date range on the x-axis.

The only options presented to me when entering the duration column to the y-axis are:

Count
UniqueCount
CountBig
Range

I was looking for the simple option of Average to show a simple line graph or bar chart of the average duration per day or month or week etc.

UPDATE: This is what I am trying to achieve but built in Excel
[image]

Anyone else come across this same issue?

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what average time would be? If you have a `DATETIME` on your category (X-Axis) then placing an `AVG` on your value (Y-Axis) would just result in 1 for all instances. Perhaps there is something else you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have added an image in my original post but built in Excel, very simple chart to build in Excel as you can see. The value would be the average of the time (duration) which creates the y-axis of a Spotfire chart/graph.

Comment: +1 to this Question, because I find it bizarre that you can do Avg([TimeColumn]) on a Cross Table, but not a Line Chart.  I had not noticed this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps to get what you want.

- Insert a calculated column `DatePart('mm',[yourDateColumn])` and name it `[Month]`
- Insert a calculated column `Avg(TimeSpan([yourDateColumn])) OVER ([Month])` and name it [AvgSpan]
- Place the `[Month]` column on your X axis
- Use `First([AvgSpan])` on your Y-Axis.

You could also use `Time()` instead of `TimeSpan()` in the expression if that's more what you want. It's hard to see what you are basing the duration off of since usually that requires a `Start` and `End` time. If you are basing the duration off the beginning of that day then you can use this logic.

- Insert calculated column `DateDiff("ss",DateTime(Date([dateField])),[dateField])` and name it [Duration]
- On your X Axis use `<BinByDateTime([yourDateColumn],"Year.Month",1)>`
- On your Y Axis use `Avg([Duration])`

Comment: Thank you @scsimon I'll take a look at that tomorrow.
The field I have for time is a duration but in time format.
Its for calculating average session time for web data, so the time is stored as a duration e.g hh:mm:ss hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Hi @scsimon just tried it out now (wasn't around yesterday) and works a treat.

Do you know if there is a way for this to work dynamically with a date aggregation? e.g. if you use the data slider to switch from date to month etc

Comment: Yeah you just need to change the bin by part and, depending on if you used the first or second method, you'll have to change the calculated column. If you used the first method you'll have to change the OVER ([Month]) you just your date field. If your date field has a time associated with it you'll need to cast it to just the date first